# Toys in parcels quantity combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

My professor said we are helping Santa Claus.

> Suppose there are $n$ parcels. The parcels are placed in order from left to right such that the leftmost parcel contains $1$ object, and each succeeding parcel contains one more object than the parcel to its left (so that the second parcel would contain $2$ objects, and the last parcel would contain $n$ objects). 
> Now, parcels contain either a toy car or a toy plane, and every object in a single parcel is the same. What is the minimum $n$ such that for every distribution of toy cars and planes among the parcels, we can find three parcels such that the number of objects in one of them plus twice the number of objects in another is equal to the number of parcels in the third, given that all three parcels must contain only toy cars or only toy planes?

I'm not really sure where to begin. My only progress is to take away the little story and write the names of the parcels as variables. I've looked at small values of $n,$ and I don't see any useful patterns. Can I get a hint as to how to start?

Comment: So when you say "every distribution", you mean every possible $n$-tuple using two symbols, for each $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @311411 Yes, basically a coloring of $n$ objects with two colors, so each of the $2^n$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python search that comes up with the answer 15 parcels, but I can't see a way of analysing the problem mathematically without a code search.

```
from itertools import combinations
  
def triples(N):
  return [x for x in combinations(range(1,N+1),3)
             if x[0]+2*x[1]==x[2] or 2*x[0]+x[1]==x[2]]

for N in range(4,20):
  print("\n",N)
  t = triples(N)
  print ( t )
  bits = [ sum(2**(i-1) for i in triple) for triple in t]

  success = True
  for n in range(2**N):
    if all ( (b&n) != 0 and (b&n) != b for b in bits):
      success=False
      print("Fails for", [x+1 for x in range(N) if (2**x)&n])
      break
  if (success):
    print ("Passes")
    break
```

For 14 parcels the candidate triples are (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 7), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 11), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 13), (1, 7, 9), (1, 8, 10), (1, 9, 11), (1, 10, 12), (1, 11, 13), (1, 12, 14), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 10), (2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 12), (2, 6, 10), (2, 6, 14), (2, 7, 11), (2, 8, 12), (2, 9, 13), (2, 10, 14), (3, 4, 10), (3, 4, 11), (3, 5, 11), (3, 5, 13), (3, 6, 12), (3, 7, 13), (3, 8, 14), (4, 5, 13), (4, 5, 14), (4, 6, 14)]

The failure case is when parcels 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 all have the same type of toy.

For 15 parcels, the triples are (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 7), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 11), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 13), (1, 7, 9), (1, 7, 15), (1, 8, 10), (1, 9, 11), (1, 10, 12), (1, 11, 13), (1, 12, 14), (1, 13, 15), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 10), (2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 12), (2, 6, 10), (2, 6, 14), (2, 7, 11), (2, 8, 12), (2, 9, 13), (2, 10, 14), (2, 11, 15), (3, 4, 10), (3, 4, 11), (3, 5, 11), (3, 5, 13), (3, 6, 12), (3, 6, 15), (3, 7, 13), (3, 8, 14), (3, 9, 15), (4, 5, 13), (4, 5, 14), (4, 6, 14), (4, 7, 15)